# PK5000Z: Forward multiple remote ports to same local port on different IPs

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, modem

I'm trying to wrangle a CenturyLink DSL modem into doing what I want.

The target configuration is as follows:

```
| Local Port | Local IP | Remote Port |
|------------|----------|-------------|
| 1337       | x.x.x.82 | 1234        |
| 1337       | x.x.x.97 | 2345        |
```

The remote ports are irrelevant, since I can use whatever I want. The local port cannot be changed, though. Both local IPs run the same server software, which unfortunately does not allow changing the local listening port in any way.

My problem implementing this is that I can have *either* local IP receive traffic, but if I try to add the second port forward the modem silently discards the rule when I save. I have confirmed that multiple port forwards are supported if the local and remote port ranges do not overlap, but for some reason the modem is refusing to save any new port forwarding rules that overlap ports with existing rules even if the local IPs are different.

Am I doing something wrong? As far as I can tell, there is no actual conflict. The modem's firmware just "doesn't want to" do it.

Comment: I'm going with the modem doesn't want to do it. You may be better off getting a cheap router that doesn't puke on a simple port forward and put the modem into bridge mode.

Comment: We should be getting fiber service soon-ish (street work started a few days before I asked this question), so I think the solution is going to be waiting until the connections (and therefore gateways) are swapped out, and trying this on the new unit…unless it takes another year to get fiber.